# How to compare an having count with subrequest in MySQl

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to compare 2 values, the 1st one will be a count() in one request, and the 2nd is a field value from another request/table but they must be related. Here's what I'm trying:

```
SELECT count(id), lead_id 
FROM calls_leads
group by lead_id
having count(id) = (
Select touches_phone_c, id_c
from leads_cstm
where lead_id = id_c)
```

Where the lead_id and id_c are the same IDs but from 2 different tables.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you mean `count(*)` in the subquery?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) AS id_cnt, lead_id
      FROM calls_leads
      GROUP BY lead_id) t INNER JOIN leads_cstm l
        ON l.id_c = t.id_cnt
```